# Terraform GCP: Unable to reach Private Kubernetes Master to create kubernetes_secret

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-secrets

When I try to reach a private Kubernetes master using a Master Authorized VM from a different VPC, where Terraform configs are executed, I am unable to reach it and Terraform errors out to create a Kubernetes secrets.

```
Error: dial tcp (master-public-or-private-endpoint):443: i/o timeout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud VPCs are configured with private IP addresses ([RFC 1918](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)). This means that VPCs cannot talk to each other using private IP addresses. RFC 1918 addresses are not routable outside the VPC.

You have a few solutions:

- Using a public IP addresses for Kubernetes. However, that defeats the purpose of setting your cluster private.
- Setup [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering). This will connect the two VPCs together. The two VPCs cannot use overlapping CIDR ranges.
- Setup a [VPN server](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/openvpn-access-server-200800/openvpn-access-server) on GCE in one VPC and connect to the VPN server from the GCE instance in the other VPC.
- Setup [Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview).

Comment: Thanks John! It sums up. I went ahead with #1, by enabling public endpoint for private cluster. I am able to reach through Master Authorized Network alone. But ended up with "kubernetes_secret.create-secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create secrets in the namespace "default"". Any help on this?

Comment: Create a new question for Kubernetes Secrets.